# hbm2ddl schema export fails due to 'Schema "XYZ" no found'

Tags: hibernate, jpa, wildfly-8, postgresql-9.4, hbm2ddl

I am trying to export a DDL to a PostgreSQL 9.4 database during start up of Wildfly 8.2.1 using Hibernate 4.3.11.

The DDL was created using hibernate-maven-plugin (http://juplo.de/hibernate-maven-plugin/), and looks like this:

```
alter table users_permissions 
    drop constraint if exists FK_eije6ps36awul7w1e8w9x0k0j;

[more alter table...]

drop table permissions cascade;

[more drop table...]

create table permissions (
    user_ID int8 not null,
    permission varchar(64) not null,
    primary key (user_ID)
);

[more create table...]

alter table users 
    add constraint UK_ey6y24h3nkw1cvrryc9khsl5p  unique (user_name, email);

[more alter table...]

create sequence hibernate_sequence;
```

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
   <persistence-unit name="${persistence.unitName}" transaction-type="JTA">
      <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
      <class>
     net.my-project.publisher.entity.UserEntity
      </class>
  <class>
     net.my-project.publisher.entity.RoleEntity
  </class>
  <class>
     net.my-project.publisher.entity.PermissionEntity
  </class>
  <properties>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"
               value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
               value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my-project"/>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.username"
               value="${postgresql.login}"/>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.password"
               value="${postgresql.password}"/>
     <property name="hibernate.default_schema"
               value="${persistence.unitName}"/>
     <property name="hibernate.dialect"
               value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
     <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection"
               value="class"/>
     <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"
               value="create"/>
     <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth"
               value="3"/>
     <property name="hibernate.show_sql"
               value="true"/>
     <property name="hibernate.format_sql"
               value="true"/>
     <property name="hibernate.order_updates"
               value="true"/>
     <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics"
               value="true"/>
     <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments"
               value="true"/>
     <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache"
               value="true"/>
     <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
               value="true"/>
     <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class"
               value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider"/>
     <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"
               value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
     <property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries"
               value="true"/>
     <property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session"
               value="false"/>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet"
               value="UTF-8"/>
  </properties>
```

Now, when the deployment to the WildFly server takes place, Hibernate analyses my persistence.xml and tries to export the DDL to my PostgreSQL database. However, that fails:

```
[org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = my-project.ear_org.postgresql.Driver_9_4
[org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment my-project.ear
[org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) JBAS011409: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'my-project.ear/persistence-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar#my-project'
[org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
[org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
[org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
[stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) Hibernate: 
[stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50)     alter table my-project.users_permissions 
[stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50)         drop constraint if exists FK_eije6ps36awul7w1e8w9x0k0j
[org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table my-project.users_permissions drop constraint if exists FK_eije6ps36awul7w1e8w9x0k0j
[org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) Schema "MY-SCHEMA" not found; SQL statement:

alter table my-schema.users_permissions 
    drop constraint if exists FK_eije6ps36awul7w1e8w9x0k0j [90079-173]
```

The funny thing about this is that I can successfully login via pgadmin3 onto my PostgreSQL server using the credentials given in the persistence.xml. Furthermore, I can access a schema called "my-schema".

Hence, something's got to be wrong with the configuration. Why is it that Hibernate cannot find the schema?

Any help is highly appreciated.
Walter

UPDATE: Sorry, there is a typo in my original post! It's not "my-project.users_permissions", but "my-schema.users_permissions".

```
[org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table my-schema.users_permissions drop constraint if exists FK_eije6ps36awul7w1e8w9x0k0j
[org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) Schema "MY-SCHEMA" not found; SQL statement:

alter table my-schema.users_permissions 
    drop constraint if exists FK_eije6ps36awul7w1e8w9x0k0j [90079-173]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access "my-schema", but the stack trace here indicates a schema called "my-project". I'd check to make sure that one exists.

```
[stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) Hibernate: 
[stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50)     alter table my-project.users_permissions 
[stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50)         drop constraint if exists FK_eije6ps36awul7w1e8w9x0k0j
[org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table my-project.users_permissions drop constraint if exists FK_eije6ps36awul7w1e8w9x0k0j
```

Comment: Um, sorry. That's my bad. That is a typo. I double-checked it. Hibernate is actually looking for my-schema.users_permissions.